# How can i get current culture with vb script?

Tags: vbscript

I need to get the current culture (The currently selected language of the system) using vb script.

We set the language of OS using "Region and Language" settings in control panel. I need to get the selected language using VB script.

Kindly reply. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [GetLocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d457t70w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)() function. It returns [LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912047%28WinEmbedded.10%29.aspx).